# Are anonymous types a good thing to use outside of LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

While analyzing some ASP.NET MVC projects I got to see anonymous types scattered all over.

HTML helpers have them:

```
<%=Html.TextBox("view.Address", "address", new { Class = "text_field" })%>
```

A lot of the return types for actions have them:

```
JsonNetResult jsonNetResult = new JsonNetResult
{
  Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
  Data = new {Something= “”}
}
```

I know this came from LINQ:

```
from p in context.Data
select new { p.Name, p.Age };
```

Are these really the correct way to accomplish things now outside of LINQ? Do they hurt code reusability and readability?

Comment: This is fairly Subjective & Argumenative, can you rewrite or edit, to be less like a troll and include your own reasons / concerns.

Comment: Voted to close as subjective/argumentative as the OP offered no actual reasoning behind his flames.

Comment: nice Edit Rich now we have a question

Comment: I agree with Josh - will vote to reopen if this does get closed.

Comment: OK, it's better now, if totally vague.

Comment: Sorry guys, I should have addressed it properly. Kudos to the community!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO, the biggest problems with anonymous types stem from the inability to name their type.  That is, it's not possible to expilictly specify the type of an anonymous type as an expression in code.  This really makes in awkward to do things like create a generic List.

```
var list = New List<No way to specify an Ananymous type>();
```

Usually you have to resort to a helper method.

```
public List<T> CreateList<T>(T notUsed) {
  return new List<T>();
}
var list = CreateList(new { .Class = "foo" });
```

This also has a larger impact in that you can't use an anonymous type as a return type, makes casting extremely awkward (need a helper method), etc ...

But these are not the operations that Anonymous Types were designed for.  In many ways they are designed to used within a particular defined function and it's subsequently created lambda expressions.  Not as a data communication type between to full fledged functions.  This is certainly a limitation in the design and at times drives me batty.  But overall I find them to be a very useful construct in the language.

Many parts of LINQ would not be possible without them in some form.

Comment: If you could give them a name then they wouldn't be anonymous :) Thinking about this another way, the real problem is that the language requires us to state a type even when the type can be inferred.

Comment: I would rather use 

    (new[] { new { Class = "foo" }, new { Class = "bar" } }).ToList()

Comment: @jachymko, that' has the overhead though of creating an array to create a List.  Not a huge overhead but one none-the-less.

Comment: @Daniel, precisely.  The problem is that type inference was added to C# and hence has many limitations.  If you look at a language like F# where type inference was in the design from day 1, you see a tremendous difference in the level of type inference.

Answer (score 3):

When the object being created is a transitory object, i.e., it's immediately consumed or converted into something else, I like the idea of anonymous types.  It prevents you from littering your code with single-purpose classes whose only use is as a short-lived container.  Your examples are typical of the types of uses where it comes in handy, i.e., in the helper extensions it's almost always immediately converted into a parameter dictionary and with the json result it gets serialized.  If the class has domain significance or needs to be used as a first-class object, then by all means create a domain class for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think of them as a better way of constructing dictionaries. Especially in your samples, what's the alternative? Passing an IDictionary<String,Object>? I think the anonymous type is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I agree

ditto passing around of lambdas and delegates instead of finding coherent domain level abstrations

Comment: Are you suggesting that all delegate passing is bad, or are you saying that you see it being abused?

Comment: I see it being used far too much - it opens a lazy short termist option up to the programmer, especially in scenarios of extending existing code.

I'd say there are rarely, if ever, absolutes when it comes to coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use them regularly to fill GridViews and DataGridViews since it saves a lot of time configuring the GridView to only show the columns I'm interested in.

Apart from settings DataSources, however, I think it would be bad for readability -- a good abstraction is probably better.